# C++ find pair from first in map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dictionary

I have created a map like this:

```
static bool bDone=false;
static std::map<int,int> mMap;
if (!bDone)
{
    bDone=true;
    mMap.insert(pair<int, int>(42810,42811));
    mMap.insert(pair<int, int>(42812,42813));
    mMap.insert(pair<int, int>(42813,42813));
    mMap.insert(pair<int, int>(42814,42815));
    }
```

I would like to find the second from the first.

For example I would like to get the value "42815" when I query for the value "42814".

How should this be done?
I am not using C11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [map::find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find):

```
std::map<int,int>::iterator it = mMap.find(42814);

if (it != mMap.end())
{
  std::cout << "The value is: " << it->second << std::endl;
}
else
{
  std::cout << "No value " << std::endl;
}
```